# Kudan Unity how to handle runtime generated meshes/ textures

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I'm having an issue where some characters I have in my Kudan AR scene are not getting textured properly. The characters are generated by a thing called UMA which essentially merges a bunch of meshes and textures together (textures into a render texture- but I tried converting that to a standard texture and still no dice) and creates a skinned mesh renderer when the scene starts (so the skinned mesh renderers are not in the scene at the very start and neither are the textures). Its almost like Kudan does some kind of scan of the objects in the scene when it starts and caches or registers any textures it finds, but because these dont exist at that point Kudan ignores them or something...  I also tried lowerng the resolution of the atlassed texture from 2048 to 1024 but that doesn't help either...

Anyway below are two pictures one of the scene using Kudan and one of the scene without Kudan... The interesting things to note is that the Hair and Eyelashes are actually there in Kudan, but these use the Unity StandardShader set to 'Fade' while the rest of the body is all one Unity opaque StandardShader with an atlassed texture...

[image: Kudan Black UMAs]
[image: UMAs how they should be]

Any ideas wht I need to do to solve this?

Comment: Looking at the ARRenderer class in the Android API there is a addTexture method, so I am wondering if Kudan in Unity basically has a unexposed method of its own that sets these when the AR scene is first loaded? I cant seem to find any way to use that method from within Unity though...

Comment: The KudanAR plugin in Unity does not deal with *any* of the rendering tasks, that is something that Unity3D takes care of. As such this seems very much like a Unity question rather than a Kudan one.

Comment: Hey MultiColorPixel, thanks for the comment. Ok so my theory maybe completely wrong, but the wierd thing is  that if simply turn the KudanTracker script off, on the Kudan camera, then play everything is fine. So it must be doing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out the 'problem' was that I was assuming the Kudan Camera moved around the ARScene (which is how Vuroria works) but it actually moves the scene around the camera.

The script in my scene that made the textures was assuming it was not going to be moved and so was bugging out. Once I worked out how Kudan was doing things it was an easy fix :)